# GetSocial error: can't find Android keystore

Tags: unity-game-engine

We have added the GetSocial plug-in in Unity. In its Android Settings it has this status:
Framework status: Downloaded
Platform status: Enabled
Push Notification status: Disabled
Signing-certificate fingerprint: [more info][refresh]

Error: Can't find Android keystore MyKeystore.keystore. Make sure Keystore is properly configured in Player Settings -> Android -> Publishing settings.

What I don't understand is that we can Build the game and upload it in Google Play. But somehow, the GetSocial plug-in don't recognize that the Keystore is already set-up correctly. With the password correct. Otherwise, the Build won't work if I'm not mistaken. Unity is already restarted but problem still occurs. Hope someone might know what causing this. THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to delete the GetSocial plug-in and it will work already.